# Money Withdrawing Calculator is always off in amount of one dollar bills given

Tags: c

I made a program in C that calculates the money to be withdrawn in the least amount of bills possible. Everything works as it should but for some reason, the amount of dollar bills given back is almost always off by one. For example, if I typed in that I wanted to withdraw 549, it would give 5 hundred dollar bills, two twenties, one five, but three dollars instead of four for a grand total of 548. If I wanted 320, it would give -1 dollars back. I'm not sure what's wrong with the program - I checked the math and everything and tried it on different compilers. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int amountToWithdraw = 0;
    int hundredsWithdrawn = 0;
    int fiftysWithdrawn = 0;
    int twentysWithdrawn = 0;;
    int tensWithdrawn= 0;
    int fivesWithdrawn= 0;
    int onesWithdrawn= 0;

    printf ("Please enter the amount of money you wish to withdraw:");
    scanf ("%d", &amountToWithdraw);

    hundredsWithdrawn = amountToWithdraw / 100;
    amountToWithdraw = amountToWithdraw % 100;
    fiftysWithdrawn = (amountToWithdraw - hundredsWithdrawn) / 50;
    amountToWithdraw = amountToWithdraw % 50;
    twentysWithdrawn = (amountToWithdraw - fiftysWithdrawn) / 20;
    amountToWithdraw = amountToWithdraw % 20;
    tensWithdrawn = (amountToWithdraw - twentysWithdrawn) / 10;
    amountToWithdraw = amountToWithdraw % 10;
    fivesWithdrawn = (amountToWithdraw - tensWithdrawn) / 5; 
    amountToWithdraw = amountToWithdraw % 5;
    onesWithdrawn = (amountToWithdraw - fivesWithdrawn) / 1;

    printf ("You received %d hundred(s)", hundredsWithdrawn);
    printf ("You received %d fifty(s)", fiftysWithdrawn);
    printf ("You received %d twenty(s)",twentysWithdrawn);
    printf ("You received %d ten(s)", tensWithdrawn);
    printf ("You received %d five(s)", fivesWithdrawn);
    printf ("You received %d one(s)", onesWithdrawn);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you type the code?, or you copied and pasted it from your editor?

Comment: Yeah I copy and pasted it onto this website.

Comment: Then you have a bug in `scanf` it's expecting `int *` and you passed `int` here `scanf ("%d", amountToWithdraw);` -> `scanf ("%d", &amountToWithdraw);`

Comment: There's some errors in the math, but more importantly, you scanf into some random memory location and get a segfault.

Comment: So **this** program cannot possibly have worked!

Comment: In the line for `fiftiesWithdrawn`, take out the `- hundredsWithdrawn`.  Do the same for all of the other amounts.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I fixed that reading error. The scanf should be fine now

Comment: @friedricek Are you allowed to use a `for` loop?

Comment: Everything listed in this program is all that is allowed to be used for now.

Comment: Then just fix the math, as all the answers suggested. The `for` loop would help you use a generic formula for both, the remaining money and the number of bills. But I suspected you was not allowed to do it that way.

Comment: `320` doesn't give `-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program logic is wrong. Instead of:

```
fiftysWithdrawn = (amountToWithdraw - hundredsWithdrawn) / 50;
```

it should be:

```
fiftysWithdrawn = amountToWithdraw / 50;
```

and similarly for all the other such lines.

You've already discarded the hundreds (by doing the `amountToWithdraw = amountToWithdraw % 100;`) so you do not need to factor them into the rest of your calculation.

---

The "off by one" error for `549` comes because on the final step you do `onesWithdrawn = (4 - 1) / 1;` giving `3` when in fact it should be `4`.  The `1` was from the bogus use of `fivesWithdrawn`. So I'd expect that you found the off-by-one error for any amounts ending in `5,6,7,8,9` and not for other amounts.

The error doesn't show up for the other notes because the amount of error is smaller than what you're dividing by, e.g. with `549` again, you do `(49 - 5) / 20` to get the number of twenties, but that gives the same answer as the correct version `49 / 20` .

BTW you might want to use the `%=` operator to make your code readable; the way it works is that `A %= B` means `A = A % B`.  And use `\n` on the end of your printf.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not a fan of using StackOverflow as a "fix my code" service, without even reading the code to begin with...

But I was curious to see how many errors are there, and in the process fixed it.

This should work reasonable well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int money = 0;
    int hundreds = 0;
    int fiftys = 0;
    int twentys = 0;
    int tens = 0;
    int fives = 0;
    int ones = 0;

    printf("Please enter the amount of money you wish to withdraw:");
    scanf("%d", &money);

    hundreds = money / 100;
    money %= 100;
    fiftys = money / 50;
    money %= 50;
    twentys = money / 20;
    money %= 20;
    tens = money / 10;
    money %= 10;
    fives = money / 5;
    money %= 5;
    ones = money / 1;

    printf("You received %d hundred(s)\n", hundreds);
    printf("You received %d fifty(s)\n", fiftys);
    printf("You received %d twenty(s)\n",twentys);
    printf("You received %d ten(s)\n", tens);
    printf("You received %d five(s)\n", fives);
    printf("You received %d one(s)\n", ones);

    return 0;
}
```

### Changes done:

1. Added ampersand to the `scanf()`
2. Fixed the math
3. Added newlines to `printf`s
4. made variable names more readable